# How to find most current visitor entrance restrictions for Israel?

Tags: covid-19, israel, event-based-effects

I would like to find out if visitors to Israel currently are limited to people with a first-degree relative in Israel.  Where can I find accurate, current information on visitor entrance restrictions for entering Israel (by air from the USA)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Israeli Ministry of Health is publishing this information [here](https://corona.health.gov.il/en/abroad/arriving-by-air/). Other than COVID restrictions, there are the standard immigration checks. US citizens do not require a visa, so you'll be assessed at the border crossing after landing and let in if no issues found.

Comment: The page says "The tourist has a health insurance policy with coverage for the
treatment of Covid19 virus". Do you know if tourists are required to show such coverage before boarding airplane in the USA?

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC I've never seen anyone being asked, but when I checked travel insurance recently for another destination that required it - it was included in the policy. I think insurers are familiar with this requirement and won't sell a policy without it.

Comment: I am not planning to buy travel health insurance.  I need to know if typical health insurance has "coverage for the treatment of Covid19 virus"

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC in the US there's no such thing as "typical health insurance". You'll have to ask your provider, and then hope that they'll abide by their own commitments when the time comes to pay. Many won't cover out of network costs, and you won't find any provider in Israel who's in a US insurance network.